# Change variable value when option is selected, return previous value when not selected anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, select

I need to update the value of a variable (which I called "tot" in the example) according to what option of a dropdown menu is selected. If I select option 1 or 2 tot must be increased of 10, if I select option 3 variable "tot" must NOT be increased. If i select option 1, and then I change my mind and select option 3 the value of Tot must be restored.

Here's the html of the select

```
<select name='hello' id='hello'>
   <option>Select an option...</option>
   <option id='one'>One</option>
   <option id='two'>Two</option>
   <option id='three'>Three</option>
</select>
```

And here's the jquery script I wrote. I guess I didn't understand the functioning of .change function, because it doesn't work as I expected.

```
var extra = 0;
var tot = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#hello').change(function(){
   if($('#one').is(':selected')) {
     extra = 10;
   }
   else if($('#two').is(':selected')) {
     extra = 10;
   }
   else if($('#three').is(':selected')) {
     extra = 0;
   }
     tot = tot + extra;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or (if I've understood what you're after correctly)....

```
var tot = 120;  //some number picked at random
var helloed = false; // flag for whether incremented 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hello").change(function(){
        var sel = $(this).find(":selected").attr("id")
        if (sel == "one" || sel =="two" ) {
            if (!helloed) {
                tot += 10;
                helloed = true;
            }
        } else { // 'three' selected
            if (helloed) {
                tot -= 10;
                helloed = false;
            }
        }
    alert ("Tot is now " + tot);    
    });
});
```

If there were more options I'd go for a switch rather than an IF but that will do for this example

Answer (score 0):

```
var extra = 0;
var tot = 0;
var initialTot = tot;

$(document).ready(function () {

   var previous = 0;
   var selected = 0;
   $('#hello').change(function(){
   if($('#one').is(':selected')) {
     previous = selected;
     selected = 1;
     extra = 10;
   }
   else if($('#two').is(':selected')) {
     previous = selected;
     selected = 2;
     extra = 10;
   }
   else if($('#three').is(':selected')) {
     previous = selected;
     selected = 3;
     extra = 0;
   }
     tot = tot + extra;
     if(previous === 1 && selected === 3) {
         tot = initialTot;
     }
   });
});
```